# there is no error or output after running the example codes (nature of code)

Tags: python, jupyter, drawing, simulation

I am trying the example codes (https://github.com/nature-of-code/noc-examples-python/tree/master/chp04_systems/NOC_4_08_ParticleSystemSmoke_b) in Jupyter. I kept the file organization as in the examples, and there is no error after compiling. But there is no output at all, even no PNG picture showed. May I know whether there is anyone else working with these example codes? How did you get the output? Thank you.

Comment: What command are you running

Comment: this code is meant to be run using P5.js, which will automatically run the setup and loop functions. Check the video where Daniel sets up the IDE to run P5.js

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by downloading the application from https://processing.org/download. And after installing the app, all the example codes are with the expected results.